# AppDelegate method applicationWillEnterForeground didn't work (worked with long delay)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, background-process

Our application use UIBackgroundMode "voip" so it can be launch in background.

In our case application was launched in background by iOS and application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions was called. Then user immediately tapped to the app icon. We don't know when it actually occurred but its look like after several seconds from background launch. After that user made some work in application, interacted with UI, but application wasn't got applicationWillEnterForeground method invoke and notifications. This method was called after 30 minutes after user worked with application. And all of this time UIApplication applicationState value was UIApplicationStateBackground. 
Why did applicationWillEnterForeground was called so later?

There is not steps to reproduce this situation because it is rare case. iOS Version is 8.1

Comment: Please edit your question to include exact problem or the steps to perfectly reproduce the issue you are facing. Check [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Otherwise you question will most likely be [closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).